# Instagram posting comment exceed rates

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm posting a comment to a content on Instagram using Instagram API.

My app is registered and approved, so I was supposed to have 60 comments per hour (or at least 30, in case it is still in Sandbox mode).

I keep getting this message:

```
The maximum number of requests per hour has been exceeded. You
have made 23 requests of the 15 allowed in the last hour
```

I can't understand where does the 15 request allowed per hour came from.
Couldn't find it anywhere in the documentation as well.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I would suggest you to go to the developer dashboard(MANAGE CLIENTS) page and report this issue. Its an option there. After that wait for a day and then check your mail. You might find a reply from them. As you have transitioned from the sandbox mode to active, the limit should increase and I hope they fix it for you

Answer (score 2):

Just some ToC I found.

> Instagram may rate limit or block apps that make a large number of
>   calls to the API that are not primarily in response to direct user
>   actions. [Details Here](https://www.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/)

And also here

> Display more than 30 Instagram photos or videos per page in your
>   application or use an unreasonable amount of bandwidth.[Found Here](https://help.instagram.com/325135857663734/?ref=hc_fnav)

It sounds like they could acutely intent to limit your requests to preserve their bandwidth. 15 requests seems like a reasonable amount, if you contact them with a reason why you'd necessarily require more they might up this limit.

Also interestingly, they can change this if they see fit

> Instagram may elect to provide you with support or modifications for
>   the Instagram APIs (collectively, "Support"), in its sole discretion,
>   and may terminate such Support at any time without notice to you.
>   Instagram may change, suspend, or discontinue any aspect of the
>   Instagram APIs at any time, including the availability of any
>   Instagram APIs. Instagram may also impose limits on certain features
>   and services or restrict your access to parts or all of the Instagram
>   APIs or the Instagram Web site without notice or liability.[Details Here](https://help.instagram.com/325135857663734/?ref=hc_fnav)

Hope this helps